# Suggest me how to achieve this

Tags: php, yii

I am creating small project managment website.
main table is `projects`. Also i have several table

`task`
`discusion`
`milestones`

all tables contain `pid`(project id) linked to specific row in project table. i whant to create tabs in proejcts views page, where user can see 
1. task tab - all tasks attached to project
2. mileston tab -all milestones
3. dicusions tab - all dicusions
...

AND for example in task tab user will see all tasks and have possibilty to create new task, manage or delete (typical crud for Task model). And same for All tabs.

Problem
I dont whant to use only one controller and do that all in the ProjectController.

But how use other controller/action in projects views page
Please suggest me right way or structure

Comment: No comments except voting down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best option would be to use Ajax calls back to the appropriate controllers to load content. You could also submit forms via Ajax ...

Comment: @user3054630 If this is the answer to your question, Stack Overflow protocol is for you to accept the answer. You then get reputation points and I do as well :-)

Answer (score -1):

1) Create new table CRUD using yii.
2) edit layout/config file for tab display.
3) insert link for new tab. 
4) You can show as you want.